# How to get value from radio button with fetch value from mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I looked everywhere and tried everything to get the selected mySQL value from a sQL queries radion button.

here is my code

```
<?php
    while($p1Result = mysql_fetch_array($p1Query))
    {?>
      <input type="radio" id="txtShop" name="txtShop" value="<?php $p1Result['buy_code'];?>"> <?php echo $p1Result['buy_code']. "  " .$p1Result['buy_name']; ?><br>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on the issue you are facing.

Comment: you want to set selected value from sql query of your radio button ? is that it ?

Comment: @ck_arjun i want to get value same as echo the radio button
Like i have 100 records and i want to show 100 records by use radio button to let user select, then i want to get value same as record that user select

Example: **Bold text is a value that i need**  _italic is value that i shown_
 <input type="radio" id="txtShop" name="txtShop" **value="<?php $p1Result['buy_code']** ;?>"> _<?php echo $p1Result['buy_code']. "?>_

Thanks ck_arjun

Answer (score 2):

In Your code echo is missing in the value

```
<?php
    while($p1Result = mysql_fetch_array($p1Query))
    {?>
      <input type="radio" id="txtShop" name="txtShop" value="<?php echo $p1Result['buy_code'];?>"> <?php echo $p1Result['buy_code']. "  " .$p1Result['buy_name']; ?><br>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: @akenaza  this is correct solution or not

Comment: this very work well ! thanks !

Comment: accept the answer if it's worked

Comment: @akenaza accept the answer if it's worked